# Do I need to pay to create interactive flash movies?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-construction

I want to create interactive movies using flash technologies. Do I need to buy a program from adobe to be able to create my flash movies or there are some free software that I can use? I would prefer something for Linux (Ubuntu).

**ADDED**

I need to program in "actionscript" and I would like to know what programs can I use to compile my code.

Comment: I fail to see how this is programming related.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe's [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) is open source and cross-platform.

Answer (score 5):

You might have a look at [Haxe](http://www.haxe.org). It supports Windows, OSX, and Linux.

Comment: It is not directly ActionScript but I would prefer haXe thousand times over all the Adobe stuff...

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of open source alternatives to using Flash CS*, or Flash/Flex Builder.  If you are looking for a free IDE, you can check out FlashDevelop at http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page.

There are some really useful libraries, frameworks, editors, utilities, etc located at http://osflash.org/open_source_flash_projects that you can look into.  It's a good list of many different alternatives.

Cheers.